# Why some executables don't have main function?

Tags: objdump

I "objdump -d" an executable, e.g, /bin/ls, and I found there's not any main function in the assembly code. Why?

Comment: Why not? *"Display assembler mnemonic names for the machine instructions. Disassemble only sections that are expected to contain instructions."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possible explanations:

1. The program in question may not be written in C. Just because C requires a `main` doesn't mean the world requires one.
2. The `main` function may have been inlined or eliminated by the compiler in general. The operating system just calls an entry point; it doesn't care if that's actually the start of a function called `main`.
3. (I'm not sure about `objdump`) `Objdump` might not expose all possible symbols in a program; given that you're pointing it at linked executable and not object files, there's not really a contract for objdump to tell you every possible function in the executable; just those which might be called externally.

Symbolic information are only mnemonics; the processor isn't looking at these things at all.

Comment: In the case of standard Linux commands like "/bin/ls", the symbols have been stripped.  Otherwise, you would (be default) see a "main()". "ls" was definitely written in C.

Comment: Additionally the name of the function might not be available at all (stripped executables) so objdump shows the function but has no name for it. Also some implementations have weird name mangling even for the main function.

Comment: @paulsm: I wasn't speaking about `ls` specifically as much as I was talking about why you might not see a main symbol in general.

Answer (score 5):

You'd probably find a "main()" in most executables that haven't been stripped:

http://linux.die.net/man/1/strip

You'd probably also see something like this if you ran the following:

```
objdump -d /bin/ls|grep main 
objdump: /bin/ls: no symbols
```